# v-show inside v-for loop displays all elements if condition is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have just started learning vuejs. One of the problem that I cant seem to find a solution to it, this one is the closest i found https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

I have a v-for loop where I loop though an array. inside that v-for loop there is also a v-show validation. It validates when one of the element in the v-for loop is pressed. if it is then it should show a new element under that element pressed. however at the moment if an element in the v-for is pressed, it shows all the elements.

```
<div v-for="size in this.clothes.size">
    <button v-on:click="renderColors()"> 
        {{size.size}}
    </button>
    <div v-show="showColor === true" v-for="colorType in size.color">
        <button v-on:click="addClothes(clothes, size, colorType)"> 
            {{colorType.color}}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

methods:{
    renderColors: function(){
        this.showColor = true;
    },
```

Current Output if one of the element is clicked:

```
Element1 (clicked)
     Child from Element1 (only this one should show)
Element2
     Child from Element2 (shouldnt show)
Element3
     Child from Element3 (shouldnt show)
```

Desire Output if one of the element is clicked:

```
Element1 (clicked)
     Child from Element1 (only this one should show)
Element2
Element3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your child elements are referring to the shared variable `showColor`, so it is logic that all child elements are shown when one of the buttons sets the variable to `true`. It would be better to create a reusable component that keeps track of the internal state like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-reusable-component v-for="(size, index) in this.clothes.size" :size="size" :key="index" :showDetails="index === showDetailsForSizeIndex" @show="showDetailsForSizeIndex = index" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showDetailsForSizeIndex: null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

MyReusableComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="$emit('show')"> 
            {{size.size}}
        </button>
        <div v-show="showDetails" v-for="colorType in size.color">
            <button v-on:click="addClothes(clothes, size, colorType)"> 
                {{colorType.color}}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        size: Object,
        showDetails: Boolean,
    },
}
</script>
```

This implementation also prevents multiple `child` elements from being shown at the same time if one would press more than one button.

Comment: Thank you that helped. Its fine that it wont prevent multiple ```child``` elements, I think i can get that sorted. Thanks

Comment: Also a quick question, you added ```:key="index``` to the ```my-reusable-component``` attribute. But you never used in the template nor in the vue script. is there a reason you added it that im not seeing?

Comment: It has become a habit/good practice, as I had some weird behavior when omitting the `key`.
From the vue docs: `To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item ... It is recommended to provide a key attribute with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.`

Comment: Hi mate, i been having trouble trying to prevent multiple child element from being shown from the above code. any ideas how I could fix this? any ideas I would really appreciate i spend yesterday and today trying to get this to work

Comment: This requirement drastically changes how one would approach this problem. I see multiple solutions, all with their pros and cons: 

1) using vuex store to keep track which 'size' has their color shown. If you don't use vuex yet, you should. I try to avoid keeping track of UI state inside the store, and reserve the store purely for data handling.

2) using handy components from 3rd party libs (for example: bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#accordion-support)

3) I modified my original solution, though for me this feels 'ugly' (small disclaimer: not tested my code)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try the version you provided plus also going to have a look at vuex.This seems something so hard to do given its such a simple task. makes me wonder whether the way i built the components is correct. Also makes me question why not just use pure javascript i would have done this long ago.